# Request buffer size for each user request to IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-8, f5

i deployed asp.net application In IIS and this applicaton can be accessed by many users from Internet , and we are usign F5 network load balancer between client and Web server. 
from IIS how can i know below points

Request buffer size for each user request to IIS
long request buffer size
max concurrent request size
number of requests per second

Here we are facing issue when users access asp.net pages from internet
this asp.net page has many dropdowns and  fields to fill the form by the user ,
some times users fill the form and change any drop down value page post backs and user session disconnected

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a packet trace (tcpdump) of the communication between the F5 BIG-IP and the IIS Server? Doing this should remove any assumptions/guess work. Take a look at this article:

https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/solutions/public/0000/400/sol411.html?sr=56628774

If the communication between the BIG-IP and IIS Server is encrypted (you are not using SSL offload on the BIG-IP), you will need to use ssldump. Instructions on that here:
https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/solutions/public/10000/200/sol10209.html?sr=56628774

This will at least show if there is a TCP RST being sent by either device. It may also show if there are any HTTP errors being sent.

Also, are you using session persistence? May a 're-load balancing' decision is being made and the user is being sent to a different server, which could also cause the behavior you describe. If that was the case, then you should look into 'cookie persistence'.

Hope that helps.